# PHP Imagick setFont not working in web but works in console

Tags: php, imagick

Here's the Code:

```
/* Create Imagick objects */
$image = new \Imagick();
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$color = new \ImagickPixel('#000000');
$background = new \ImagickPixel('none'); // Transparent

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont("annabelle");
$draw->setFontSize(80);
$draw->setFillColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

/* Get font metrics */
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

/* Create text */
$draw->annotation(0, $metrics['ascender'], $text);

/* Create image */
$image->newImage($metrics['textWidth'], $metrics['textHeight'], background);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->drawImage($draw);

/* Save image */
file_put_contents('imagick_test.png', $image);
?>
```

And ImageMagick configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<typemap>
   <include file="type-dejavu.xml" />
   <include file="type-ghostscript.xml" /> 
   <include file="type-windows.xml" />
   <type name="annabelle" family="annabelle" glyphs="/home/nginx/testing/annabelle.ttf" />
</typemap>
```

If I call this in console mode by: php -f test.php, it's OK. But when I accessing by web interface: http://test-srv/testing/test.php, It raise an exception:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'The path does not exist: /home/nginx/testing/annabelle' in /home/nginx/testing/test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 /home/nginx/testing/test.php(15): ImagickDraw->setfont('annabelle') #1 {main} thrown in /home/nginx/testing/test.php on line 15

I tried use setFontFamily() instead of setFont() like this:

```
...
/* Font properties */
$draw->setFontFamily("annabelle");
$draw->setFontSize(80);
...
```

Or using the font file instead using font name in setFont() like this:

```
...
/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont("annabelle.ttf");
$draw->setFontSize(80);
...
```

The image created like this:
[image: Wrong one]

The right one should like this if I run the code in cosole:
[image: Right one]

Comment: This probably a file permissions thing. Can you check if the font file is readable by PHP when running through the webserver. e.g. something like "echo strlen(file_get_contents("/home/nginx/testing/annabelle.ttf"));"

Comment: It get the length 74144, and I call the php -f test.php command by user nginx which used to run the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I get the answer.

I've upgraded php from 5.5 to 5.6, than I found Imagick module disabled so I re-emerge Imagick with PHP_TARGET="php5-6" (I'm running gentoo). But I forget restart php-fpm service. After I restart the service, it runs right.